# What does the "self" keyword references in this Ruby case?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, self

I would like some help understanding what does `self` refers to in this case. I understand that `self` refers to the class, module, etc that "owns" the code currently executing. In my example, `my_each` is an instance method for the `Enumerable` module. I'd like to know how does the `self` keyword works so that when I pass it to my example array it references it.

```
module Enumerable
    def my_each
        i = 0
        while i < self.size
            yield(self[i])
            i += 1
        end
        self
    end
end
```

```
[2,4,5].my_each { |i|
    puts i
}

=> 2
=> 4
=> 5
```

Comment: It refers to an instance of a class which extends Enumerable, in the case of your last example, it’s the Array itself.

Answer (score 2):

What `self` refers to depends on the context. In your case, in an instance method, `self` refers to the object receiver of your instance method, so in your case the array `[2, 4, 5]`.

But `self` can refer to other objects too. For example,

```
class Foo
  puts self
end
```

prints `Foo` because in that context `self` refers to the class object. And that's why the two following definitions are the same thing

```
class Foo
  def Foo.m
  end
end

class Foo
  def self.m
  end
end
```

Comment: my pleasure sir :)

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby it's all about self and every method is always executed against a particular self. 
In your example instance method my_each self will refer to an instance which is using the method. 
As you said self can also refer to a class, module..
It is a very powerfull ruby keyword since it can be used to create metaclasses. 
If you are interested in understanding more I suggest you read chapter 5 in The Well Grounded Rubyist

Answer (score 0):

self is a special variable that points to the object that "owns" the currently executing code. Ruby uses self everywhere:

1. For instance variables: @myvar
2. For method and constant lookup
3. When defining methods, classes and modules.

**Inside of an instance method**

In the code below, reflect is an instance method. It belongs to the object we created via Event.new. So self points to that object.

```
class Event
  def reflect
    self
  end
end

g = Event.new
g.reflect == g # => true
```

**Inside of a class method**

For this example, reflect is a class method of Ghost. With class methods, the class itself "owns" the method. self points to the class.

```
class Event
  def self.reflect
    self
  end
end

Event.reflect == Event # => true
```

It works the same with "class" methods inside of modules. For example:

```
module Event
  def self.reflect
    self
  end
end 
Event.reflect == Event # => true
```

Remember, classes and modules are treated as objects in Ruby. So this behavior isn't that different from the instance method behavior we saw in the first example.

**Inside of a class or module definition**

One feature of Ruby that makes it such a good fit for frameworks like Rails is that you can execute arbitrary code inside class and module definitions. When you put code inside of a class/module definition, it runs just like any other Ruby code. The only real difference is the value of self.

As you can see below, self points to the class or module that's in the process of being defined.

```
class Event
  self == Event # => true
end 

module Join
  self == Join # => true
end
```

**Inside mixin methods**

Mixed-in methods behave just like "normal" instance or class methods when it comes to self. This makes sense. Otherwise the mixin wouldn't be able to interact with the class you mixed it into.

*Instance methods*

Even though the reflect method as defined in the module, its self is the instance of the class it was mixed into.

```
module Reflection
  def reflect
    self
  end
end 

class Event
  include Reflection
end

g = Event.new
g.reflect == g # => true
```

*Class methods*

When we extend a class to mix in class methods, self behaves exactly like it does in normal class methods.

```
module Reflection
  def reflect
    self
  end
end 

class Event
  extend Reflection
end

Event.reflect == Event # => true
```

**Inside the metaclass**

Chances are you've seen this popular shortcut for defining lots of class methods at once.

```
class Event
  class << self 
    def method1
    end

    def method2
    end
  end
end
```

The class << foo syntax is actually pretty interesting. It lets you access an object's metaclass - which is also called the "singleton class" or "eigenclass." I plan on covering metaclasses more deeply in a future post. But for now, you just need to know that the metaclass is where Ruby stores methods that are unique to a specific object.

If you access self from inside the class << foo block, you get the metaclass.

```
class << "test"
  puts self.inspect
end

# => #<Class:#<String:0x007f8de283bd88>
```

**Outside of any class**

If you're running code outside of any class, Ruby still provides self. It points to "main", which is an instance of Object:

```
puts self.inspect # => main
```